# CSS File Not Loading in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, sass

[I have this HTML + CSS + js](http://miracle-acupuncture.com/).

If you look view it in Chrome or IE, the page renders perfectly. However, FF doesn't seem to be loading the CSS file. I'm 99% certain that it's pointing to the right directory.

```
css/stylesheets/miracle.css
```

It's published using Github pages, and the css is compiled from a scss file using SASS. If anyone could point me in the right direction, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try taking out your charset declaration, just for spits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firefox doesn't like the `@charset "IBM437";` declaration at the top of your `miracle.css` file. Try removing this line.

It looks like this may be added to your output by SASS, so you should check the encoding of your source (scss) files to determine where SASS is getting this from.

Comment: Yup, that's probably the issue. Thanks so much!

Comment: Adding @charset "utf-8"; to the top of the scss file solved it. Thank you so much.